# Can I use "although" at the beginning of a paragraph?

Tags: writing-style, paragraphs

For instance...

"Although it is hot outside, I put my jacket on. I then proceeded to take it on and off, all day long. I am not sure why I did this."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no grammatical rule against using "although" at the beginning of a sentence or at the beginning of a paragraph.

This is more a question of style and how you wish to present the language you are using or the story you are telling.